# UITableView cells are not displaying text

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I just finished a simple 5 minute UITableView tutorial. I even imported the tutorial's source code files into my own current xcode project, and I still cannot get this to work. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if it's because the tutorial was created using a different version of xcode or what.

Anyways, I created a new objective-c file called "TVTViewController" which is a subclass of UIViewController. I then dragged a UIViewController onto the storyboard and set it's custom class in the attributes inspector to "TVTViewController".

Next, I dragged a UITableView object onto the UIViewController that I just dragged onto the storyboard.

I set the UITableView's "Content" setting to "Dynamic" and then set it's "Prototype Cells" setting to "1".

I then selected the prototype cell on the storyboard, and changed it's "Style" setting to "Subtitle", and changed it's "Identifier" setting to "SettingsCell".

Finally, here is my header file code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TVTViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

And here is my main file's code:

```
#import "TVTViewController.h"

@interface TVTViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tweetsArray;
@end

@implementation TVTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  //1
  self.tableView.dataSource = self;
  //2
  self.tweetsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      @"Always put your fears behind you and your dreams in front of you.",
                      @"A relationship with no trust is like a cell phone with no service, all you can do is play games.",
                      @"People should stop talking about their problem and start thinking about the solution.",
                      @"Dear Chuck Norris, Screw you. I can grill burgers under water. Sincerely, Spongebob Squarepants.",
                      @"My arms will always be open for you, they will never close, not unless you're in them.",
                      nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//3
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [self.tweetsArray count];
}

//4
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //5
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";
  //6
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


  NSString *tweet = [self.tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  //7
  [cell.textLabel setText:tweet];
  [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"via Codigator"];
  return cell;
}
@end
```

When I run my app on my iPhone, it shows the table view, but it is empty. None of the text is displayed in the table view's cells at all. This is pretty much copy and pasted from the tutorial's source code, and when I run the tutorial's source code app on my iPhone it displays the text in the cells just fine.

I don't understand why it is not working for me once I add the same code to my own app.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

I just figured it out on my own. The tutorial author neglected to tell you to connect the IBOutlet called "tableView" to the UITableView object. I just connected them and everything is displaying fine now. I would answer my own question but stackoverflow won't let me for another 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UITableViewDelegate`, like

```
@interface TVTViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

with

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

And create cell as

```
if(cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around:

a) Check that the cell were actually created or not:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if( !cell )
{

   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
}
```

b) Set its `delegate` and `datasource`

Check out [other ways](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a) to dequeue table view cells